# Promise with query binding doesnt end

Tags: mysql, node.js, data-binding, promise

I having this function `query` in my module `mysqlFunction` in NodeJs. The functions work without a problem when the query hasn't had binding, but when I use a binding, for example, to use a parameter in `WHERE` or an `INSERT`, the promise doesn't end and the request never finishes. The strange thing is that the instructions are executed, for example, the fields are inserted in the table, or the select returns the data.

```
//mysqlFunction.js
const mysql = require("MySQL");
const pool = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);
const query = (sql, binding) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(sql, [binding], (err,result) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
};

//Calling the function
const exampleId = 1;
const sql = `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?`;
mysqlFunction.query(sql, exampleId, (error, results) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    if (results.length > 0){
        res.json (results);
    } else {
        res.send('No result')
    }
});
```

Comment: You should be cautious with `if (err) reject(err); resolve(result)`. In the event of `err` you are attempting to `reject` **and** `resolve` the promise. Promises are designed to prevent this, but still you shouldn't write code that attempts to do this. Writing this as `if (err) reject(err); else resolve(result)` makes more logical sense and is safer and only _one_ branch will be executed. This might not seem like a big deal to you, but writing this kind of `if` statement is the source of many painful bugs and I recommend you learn to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node has a built-in utilility, [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) which converts a node-style error-first callback function, `(err, result) => ...`, to a Promise-returning function -

```js
// mysqlFunction.js

const mysql =
  require("MySQL")

const util =
  require("util")

const pool =
  mysql.createPool(dbConfig)

const query =
  util.promisify(pool.query.bind(pool))

module.exports = { query: query }
```

The point of Promise and `async`/`await` syntax is to avoid writing error-prone callbacks. Your code stays flat and you can reason about it in a synchronous way.

```js
const mysqlFunction =
  require("./mysqlFunction.js")

const exampleId = 1

const sql = `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?`

try {
  res.json(await mysqlFunction.query(sql, [exampleId])) // await
}
catch (err) {
  res.send(err.message)                // handle errors
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!
My problem was solved only using the second part of the solution, adding await inside of try/catch.
About the first part, I couldn't add the binding to the SQL, so didn't work for me.